# Why is setFollowRedirects(boolean auto) a static method of HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, static, httpurlconnection

Why is the the setFollowRedirects method static? I am in a situation where I would like to follow redirects or not on a per-connection basis, and while its not hard to change the global flag before each connection, I'm curious why it was implemented that way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looks like you can use [`setInstanceFollowRedirects()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setInstanceFollowRedirects%28boolean%29) to alter the default behaviour defined in [`setFollowRedirects()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setFollowRedirects%28boolean%29) on a per connection basis.

Once [`setFollowRedirects()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setFollowRedirects%28boolean%29) is called, all connections created afterwards will use this value as default.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder who had the glorious idea to choose these names, when all the other static methods are called `setDefaultXXX` with corresponding `setXXX` methods for the instance methods...